# how can send variable value through pagination links?

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

***SOLVED***
I was trying to create pagination on the home page.

my default controller :

```
$route['default_controller'] ="home";
```

**problem 1:**
 for pagination if I write-

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'home/index'; // index function
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
$config['per_page'] = 10;
$limit = array($config['per_page'] => $this->uri->segment(3));
```

then it works but it shows 'localhost/baseurl/home/index/10' on browser address bar.I want to show just 'localhost/baseurl/10' (while 'localhost/baseurl/' is my homepage and I want pagination on there).so I wrote

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url(); // index function
$config['uri_segment'] = 1;
$config['per_page'] = 10;
$limitt = array($config['per_page'] => $this->uri->segment(1));
```

but that doesn't work. how can I do that ?

**problem 2:**

how can I send a variable value through pagination link like
localhost/baseurl/home/index?search=y/10

I wrote:

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'home/index?search=y';
```

but this doesn't work. it receives `search=y/10`. not only `y` and the pagination doesn't find `10` on `$this->uri->segment(3))`

so whats the correct way to do that?

***Edit:***

my htaccess code is:-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./mysite/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

this code shows my site address like 'localhost/mysite/'. but if I set the base url of the pagination like

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url();
$config['uri_segment'] = 1;
$config['per_page'] = 10;
$limitt = array($config['per_page'] => $this->uri->segment(1));
```

then the number shows on pagination link like 'localhost/mysite/10' but the value '10' not received by the script. if I write-

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'home/index';  // 'index' is the function in 'home' class
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
$config['per_page'] = 10;
$limitt = array($config['per_page'] => $this->uri->segment(3));
```

then it works but the browser address line becomes 'localhost/mysite/home/index/10' what I don't like. whats the way to solve the first problem ?

Comment: For the first problem you'll need to define a rewrite rule in your .htaccess file, for the second problem enable the option 'page_query_string' so you don't need to use uri->segements it will send it as _GET variable instead.

Comment: the second problem was solved.declared 'page_query_string' as TRUE. but the first problem still is there. my htaccess file code is in my edit part. how should I change that to solve the first problem ?

Comment: hmm.. try something like this in your routes.php first: $route['(:num)'] = "home/index/$1";

Comment: could you please explain more ? in my routes.php there '$route['default_controller'] ="home/";' I tried '$route['default_controller'] ="home/index/";' but that didn't work for uri->segment(1). it seems uri->segment(1) [like 'localhost/mysite/10'] not found by server. always shows 'page not found'.

Comment: I Know you have set your default controller, but since you're trying to use pagination directly without specifying "controller/method/offset" and you're only looking to have "/offset" in your home url, then you'll have to define the route I've given to you which will match any num at the beginning of the url and move it to the appropriate controller (the default controller).

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem you will have to define a `rewrite rule` as in the first comment.
For the second problem do like this,

```
if($this->uri->segment(3)){
    $keyword = $this->uri->segment(3);
}
else if($this->input->get('search')){
    $keyword = $this->input->get('search');
}

$config['base_url']     = base_url().'home/index/'.$keyword.'/page/';
$config["uri_segment"]  = 5;
```

Comment: my second problem was solved.I followed ahmad's comment. but first problem still need to be solved. see my htaccess code there. that removes 'index.php' from site address on browser address bar. so how should I change that to solve the first problem ? whats new should I write there ?